# What is wrong with my self referencing entity class?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

The mapped category table looks like this:

```
id | parent_id | name
```

And the entity class:

```
class Category
{

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 */
protected $id;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="parent_id", type="integer") <-- if removed it works
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="children")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $parent;


/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="parent")
 */
protected $children;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string")
 */
protected $name;


/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="category")
 */
protected $products;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
}

}
```

In Symfony profiler I get the following mapping errors:

The association Test\TestBundle\Entity\Category#children refers to the owning side field Test\TestBundle\Entity\Category#parent which is not defined as association.

The association Test\TestBundle\Entity\Category#children refers to the owning side field Test\TestBundle\Entity\Category#parent which does not exist.

And also a error notice :

```
Notice: Undefined index: parent in C:\inetpub\www\Symfony\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister.php line 1575
```

Why? My class is basicly just a copy/paste from the manual.

## **Edit:**

After I removed the column name annonation it works (name defaults to column name anyway):

```
* @ORM\Column(name="parent_id", type="integer")
```

But why? In my production table the column name may change

Comment: Not an answer but should the `ManyToOne` be on the children rather than the parent?

Comment: No the relation is correct

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use `@ORM\Column` tag when you can use `@ORM\JoinColumn` please explain

Comment: I thought they were two different things but I can see they are related in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like problem was the `@ORM\Column` annonation added to `$parent`. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `@ORM\Column` annotation when you're also defining a relation like `@ORM\ManyToOne`.

In that case, the name of the column is automatically calculated or (as you did already) you may override it with the `@ORM\JoinColumn(...)` annotation.